# When and how to close resources if they are members of the struct

Tags: go

Here is classical example of using defer:

```
conn, err = amqp.Dial(rabbitMqConnectionString)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
```

In my case the connection is the member of struct and I am using this connnection in the different functions:

```
type MyServer {
  conn *Connection
}

func (s *MyServer) Run() {
  s.conn, err = amqp.Dial(rabbitMqConnectionString)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

func (s *MyServer) DoSomethingWithConnection() {
  // ...do something with connection
}
```

In this case I cannot use defer in the `Run()` method. But where and how do I need to close connection in this case ?

Comment: You need to close the connection whenever you don't need it anymore. In other languages there is a notion of destructors, in Go you must truck it yourself manually.

Comment: @zerkms If I understand correctly, the `defer` give us guarantee that the connection will be closed. In this case we don't have such guarantee....

Comment: `defer` is just a language construction that runs an arbitrary function after the current function returns. Everything else is the semantics you put yourself. As I already mentioned - you need to close it as soon as you don't need it anymore, and you must track it manually since the language does not provide any other tool for that.

Comment: @zerkms, If I understand correctly I need to write `Close()` function for my struct and use `defer` with my struct variable, right ?

Comment: You use `defer` to run an arbitrary function. Do you have any appropriate place where you could have used `defer` for this particular problem?

Comment: I have created instance of my struct in the other function. And it will be fine to release all resources when this function returns.

Comment: "And it will be fine to release all resources when this function returns." --- so do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func (s *MyServer) Stop() {
    //Some teardown
   s.conn.Close()
}
func main(){
    var s *MyServer
    ...
    s.Run()
    defer s.Stop()
    s.DoSomethingWithConnection()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see i [`streadway/amqp/integration_test.go`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/7039654952f68968b17922b8dd15a6c0e2b41b7d/integration_test.go#L989-L991), the function using a connexion is responsible for closing it:

```
if c := integrationConnection(t, "txcommit"); c != nil {
    defer c.Close()
    ...
}
```

with:

```
// Returns a connection to the AMQP if the AMQP_URL environment
// variable is set and a connection can be established.
func integrationConnection(t *testing.T, name string) *Connection {
    conn, err := Dial(integrationURLFromEnv())
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("dial integration server: %s", err)
        return nil
    }
    return loggedConnection(t, conn, name)
}
```

And:

```
func loggedConnection(t *testing.T, conn *Connection, name string) *Connection {
    if name != "" {
        conn.conn = &logIO{t, name, conn.conn}
    }
    return conn
}
```